# Cross-thread operations in C++ without SendMessage

Tags: c++, multithreading, sendmessage

I'm looking for a way to perform cross-thread operations the way SendMessage allows. In other words, how to have a thread execute some function in another thread. But I want to do it without SendMessage as that requires a window which is not always available.

Synchronously or asynchronously is fine.

.NET does it with the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher class, so surely there's a way?

Comment: You need a work queue with the target thread being stuck processing its items, which is exactly what the `Dispatcher` class provides in .NET.

Comment: What function(s) exactly would I need to use? I'm looking at the "Thread Pool API" documentation but it seems it can only queue operations on special worker threads. What if a worker thread needs to queue an operation on the main UI thread?

Comment: It seems weird to people not used to native Windows development, but having an invisible window is incredibly common. There are many situations where a thread will need one even if it never displays a single user visible element and this is perfectly acceptable. So just create a window if you have to exchange or listen for messages. Although it might be a good idea to explain your actual problem - it's rare that you have to execute something on a specific thread.

Comment: If you have an UI thread use SendMessage, just create a message-only window and use it for cross-thread business.

Comment: Well ok... I can do that, but I was just looking to improve a design I have. After all, this seems like a functionality that should be available by itself instead of being tied to window creation.

Comment: @user1610015: uhm, not really, are you requiring the system to give you the ability to hijack another thread to make it do random stuff? That's not going to happen, for the simple reason that you couldn't do almost anything reliably into a "stolen" thread (that's the exact same problem of signals in Unix). Again, to make it work fine the target thread must be part of your scheme, and thus either have a tasks-only queue (like the one implemented by @DavidHaim) - or, if you already have a message queue (like you have in the UI thread), you should exploit it - hence SendMessage.

Comment: @MatteoItalia It's not hijacking, unless you consider SendMessage or QueueUserAPC or Dispatcher.Invoke to be hijacking.

Comment: @user1610015: in facts that's not hijacking - what all these functions do is to queue a work item into a message queue, and, on the other side, you have to have the other thread check the queue - using `GetMessage` for `SendMessage`, a number of alertable wait functions for APC stuff (although it's *quite* similar to hijacking, and in facts it's not recommended) and whatever `Dispatcher` uses to work. If you hijack the instruction pointer of another thread at will you may get into your function while the thread is holding - for example - the allocator lock - bam, you have deadlock.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Ok, so where did you get that I want to hijack another thread? What I asked about was exactly what these functions do, and I didn't know about QueueUserAPC which seems like the best choice. Problem solved.

Comment: The point is: you need active collaboration in the target thread, so that it can execute what you are asking for in a "safe" moment. Brutal instruction pointer hijacking (interrupt-style AKA Unix-signals-style) cannot work for calling a generic function (the actions you can do safely in a signal handler are just calling a handful of syscalls and writing to variables of a certain type). APC is dangerous as well, because you are executing user code when the target thread code thinks to be sleeping. If it isn't written with this in mind, you risk deadlock for similar reasons.

Comment: @user1610015: my problem is that you are juggling with chainsaws without understanding what's going on under the hood, and with threading stuff it's extremely easy to get hurt - three months later, in production, at random intervals, on the machine of a customer on the other side of the world. `QueueUserAPC` is an extremely low level tool that requires great care to get right, I would never use it unless there's no other alternative. Trust me, use `SendMessage` or some other higher level primitive.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Ok I'll follow the advice. But that makes me wonder how Dispatcher does it. It doesn't seem tied to window creation (so no SendMessage) and the docs don't warn about the problems associated with QueueUserAPC.

Comment: @MatteoItalia `APC` is not more dangerous than any standard task queue you'd write yourself. it cannot hurt you more than any standard concurrency object may. it may be the opposite - instead of writing your own stuff, you use something that was written and tested for decades. APC is not more dangerous than any other multi threading code you'd write in C++11. I think you misunderstand the basic sense of that question that the user simply wants something equivalent to to `SendMessage` without actually having a window-message queue. user APC is just that.

Comment: From what I read Dispatcher works for WPF and Windows Forms UI threads, so it's going to be implemented with SendMessage on Windows Forms (exactly as Control.Invoke), and I guess with a WPF event in WPF (not really sure, I never used WPF, but seems to be implemented with the usual message queues as any other UI framework). I'll have a look later with reflector to see what's actually going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm guessing we're talking about Windows OS here, right? you should specify that in your question. A solution for Windows might be a different for a solution for Linux, for example.

now, regarding your question, any solution for that situation will force your thread(s) to either wait on some event to happen (enqueuing a task), or poll for a task endlessly.

So we're talking about either some kind of a mutex, a condition variable or some special sleeping function.

One (simple) and non portable way or sending "tasks" to other threads is to use the builtin Win32 - mechanism of `APC` (**A**synchronous **P**rocedure **C**all).

it utilizes the functions [QueueUserAPC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684954(v=vs.85).aspx)   and [SleepEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686307(v=vs.85).aspx), I have mini tested this solution on my Windows 10 + Visual studio 2015

```
namespace details {
    void waitforTask() noexcept {
        SleepEx(INFINITE, TRUE);
    }

    void __stdcall executeTask(ULONG_PTR ptr) {
        if (ptr == 0) {
            return;
        }
        std::unique_ptr<std::function<void()>> scopedPtr(reinterpret_cast<std::function<void()>*>(ptr));
        (*scopedPtr)();
    }
}

template<class F, class ... Args>
void sendTask(void* threadHandle, F&& f, Args&& ... args) {
    auto task =
        std::make_unique<std::function<void()>>(std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...));

    const auto res = QueueUserAPC(&details::executeTask,
        threadHandle,
        reinterpret_cast<ULONG_PTR>(task.get()));
    if (res == 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error("sendTask failed.");
    }

    task.release();
}
```

Example use:

```
std::thread thread([] {
        for (;;) {
            details::waitforTask();
        }
    });

   sendTask(thread.native_handle(), [](auto literal) {
        std::cout << literal;
   }, "hello world");
```

this solution also shows how to use Win32 without actually contaminating the business logic written in C++ code non related win32 code.

this solution also can be adapted to a cross platform solution, instead of using an internal, semi-documented win32 task queue, one can build his own task queue using `std::queue` and `std::function<void()>`. instead of sleeping in alertable state, one can use `std::condition_variable` instead. this is what any thread-pool does behind the scenes in order to get and execute tasks. If you do want a cross-platform solution, I suggest googling "C++ thread pool" in order to see examples of such task queue.

Comment: Thanks, QueueUserAPC is exactly what I need. Do you know if there is a synchronous equivalent?

Comment: define synchronous in this contex.

Comment: What it sounds like really... like the opposite of the "A" in APC. Maybe something like QueueUserSPC? :D

Comment: so, basically you want thread A to  enqueue a task to thread B and wait for thread B to finish the task? I don't understand the question. asking another thread to do something while you do something else **is** (one) the definition of asynchronous

Comment: Take for example the way SendMessage does it - it waits for the window procedure to handle the message and then returns. This is also the difference between the Dispatcher.Invoke and Dispatcher.BeginInvoke methods.

Comment: @user1610015 this is a really bad thing to do. if you must make the thread stuck, add win32 event to your function, and make the function set that event when the function ends. then wait on that event in the queuing thread. again, this misses the whole point of asynchronous code.